# sharePoint 2010 User Profile Syncronization - Not Starting.. Libutils.cpp Cannot find the file specified

Tags: user-profile-service, kerberos, restart

Brand new SP2010 install patched up to August 2011 CU.

Used wizard to install everything.

Attempt to start User Profile Synchronization, but it just reads "starting".

I have another install on another server working great, using the same service account.

Here's what I've done on both farms with no luck:

1. CHANGED THE SERVICE ACCOUNT ON BOTH FIM PROCESS THROUGH SERVICES.
2. ADDED THE SERVICE ACCOUNT TO LOCAL ADMINS ON EACH SERVER
3. ADDED SETSPNS FOR THE SERVERS AND ACCOUNTS
4. SET SERVERS HAVE TRUST THIS COMPUTER FOR DELIGATION SET IN AD

Again, both farms are using the same service account for the service. So settings on the account are identical.  I even stop and restarted UPSS on the workikng one and  it comes up fine.  I can reproduce the error by restarting the serverice from Services too.

Lots of reboots and gpupdate /force. We are using Kerberos security. I have not created a new application for the service, but I did not have to on the prior install that is working perfectly. Compared everything and just don't see why this is not working.

here's the exact error I am gettting in the event log:

On screen Service Specfic error -2146234334

in th event log:

Log Name:      Application
Source:        FIMSynchronizationService
Date:          9/16/2011 2:36:26 PM
Event ID:      6324
Task Category: Server
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      <>
Description:
The server encountered an unexpected error and stopped.

"ERR: MMS(2256): libutils.cpp(10513): RegQueryValueEx of Server failed with 2
BAIL: MMS(2256): libutils.cpp(10515): 0x80070002 (The system cannot find the file specified.)
ERR: MMS(2256): libutils.cpp(10513): RegQueryValueEx of SQLInstance failed with 2
BAIL: MMS(2256): libutils.cpp(10515): 0x80070002 (The system cannot find the file specified.)
ERR: MMS(2256): libutils.cpp(10513): RegQueryValueEx of DBName failed with 2
BAIL: MMS(2256): libutils.cpp(10515): 0x80070002 (The system cannot find the file specified.)
BAIL: MMS(2256): server.cpp(359): 0x80070002 (The system cannot find the file specified.)
BAIL: MMS(2256): server.cpp(3860): 0x80070002 (The system cannot find the file specified.)
BAIL: MMS(2256): service.cpp(1531): 0x80070002 (The system cannot find the file specified.)
ERR: MMS(2256): service.cpp(980): Error creating com objects. Error code: -2147024894. This is retry number 0.
BAIL: MMS(2256): clrhost.cpp(224): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): scriptmanagerimpl.cpp(7670): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): server.cpp(251): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): server.cpp(3860): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): service.cpp(1531): 0x80131022 
ERR: MMS(2256): service.cpp(980): Error creating com objects. Error code: -2146234334. This is retry number 1.
BAIL: MMS(2256): clrhost.cpp(224): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): scriptmanagerimpl.cpp(7670): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): server.cpp(251): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): server.cpp(3860): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): service.cpp(1531): 0x80131022 
ERR: MMS(2256): service.cpp(980): Error creating com objects. Error code: -2146234334. This is retry number 2.
BAIL: MMS(2256): clrhost.cpp(224): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): scriptmanagerimpl.cpp(7670): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): server.cpp(251): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): server.cpp(3860): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): service.cpp(1531): 0x80131022 
ERR: MMS(2256): service.cpp(980): Error creating com objects. Error code: -2146234334. This is retry number 3.
BAIL: MMS(2256): service.cpp(994): 0x80131022 
Forefront Identity Manager 4.0.2450.34"
Event Xml:

  
    
    6324
    2
    3
    0x80000000000000
    
    14805
    Application
    myserver here
    
  
  
    ERR: MMS(2256): libutils.cpp(10513): RegQueryValueEx of Server failed with 2
BAIL: MMS(2256): libutils.cpp(10515): 0x80070002 (The system cannot find the file specified.)
ERR: MMS(2256): libutils.cpp(10513): RegQueryValueEx of SQLInstance failed with 2
BAIL: MMS(2256): libutils.cpp(10515): 0x80070002 (The system cannot find the file specified.)
ERR: MMS(2256): libutils.cpp(10513): RegQueryValueEx of DBName failed with 2
BAIL: MMS(2256): libutils.cpp(10515): 0x80070002 (The system cannot find the file specified.)
BAIL: MMS(2256): server.cpp(359): 0x80070002 (The system cannot find the file specified.)
BAIL: MMS(2256): server.cpp(3860): 0x80070002 (The system cannot find the file specified.)
BAIL: MMS(2256): service.cpp(1531): 0x80070002 (The system cannot find the file specified.)
ERR: MMS(2256): service.cpp(980): Error creating com objects. Error code: -2147024894. This is retry number 0.
BAIL: MMS(2256): clrhost.cpp(224): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): scriptmanagerimpl.cpp(7670): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): server.cpp(251): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): server.cpp(3860): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): service.cpp(1531): 0x80131022 
ERR: MMS(2256): service.cpp(980): Error creating com objects. Error code: -2146234334. This is retry number 1.
BAIL: MMS(2256): clrhost.cpp(224): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): scriptmanagerimpl.cpp(7670): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): server.cpp(251): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): server.cpp(3860): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): service.cpp(1531): 0x80131022 
ERR: MMS(2256): service.cpp(980): Error creating com objects. Error code: -2146234334. This is retry number 2.
BAIL: MMS(2256): clrhost.cpp(224): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): scriptmanagerimpl.cpp(7670): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): server.cpp(251): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): server.cpp(3860): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(2256): service.cpp(1531): 0x80131022 
ERR: MMS(2256): service.cpp(980): Error creating com objects. Error code: -2146234334. This is retry number 3.
BAIL: MMS(2256): service.cpp(994): 0x80131022 
Forefront Identity Manager 4.0.2450.34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing anything more please read Spencer Harbars guide on the topic - if you follow that one you should not fail: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx

Secondly; never ever run the Farm Configuration Wizard (FCW aka the white wizard) if you're doing anything but a test setup.

Third; never ever try to fix UPS by manual "hacking" such as changing the service account in the Services console. If you follow the previously mentioned guide all this is done for you - in the correct way.

Fourth; you can/should not change the account used for the UPS - it must **always** be the farm account!

Comment: Thanks.. I have reviewed that guide. The problem was there before I changes the user to my farm user. And actually I have the service running perfectly on another server in this configuration farm too. But no mater what I do not , I can't get that Service to go to Stopped. I've tried running the reset powershelll script on that site. I'm not sure what else I can do. It's my first server on the farm and was going to be the app server. Is it even possible to just do a full reinstall of that server?